# Configuration system failed to initialize in .NET

Tags: vb.net, file, configuration

I have an .NET winforms application(A). I am calling another .NET exe(B) file from the winforms application. When executes, it throws the following error.

I haven't kept any configuration file for the second exe file(B).

> "Configuration system failed to initialize"

Comment: Make sure to check the date of an answer below. Find the most recent one. Some of these are like 11 years old, and things have changed since then.

Answer (score 8):

I encountered the same error for a program that I wrote to override the caps Lock controller.  The "Configuration system failed to initialize" error occurred many months after the program had been in use. Because I configured the program to start automatically on reboot, I would see the error every time I restarted my (Windows 7) PC.

Although I did not intentionally create a configuration file, one was created by the .NET framework in a `Users \#Username#\AppData\Local\#ProgramName_vsho_URL_#random_characters\#version_number\` folder.  Deleting the `user.config` file in that folder resolved the problem.

Comment: In my case the file was present, but empty. Must have been corrupted somehow. Deleting it fixed the problem. Thanks Robert

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem while running a visual studio project. I deleted all files in "C:\Users#UserName#\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio#ProjectName#". Then it worked without "Configuration system failed to initialize" error.

Comment: Thanks - the rest of these answers are so old and are no longer accurate.

Comment: This solved the issue for me. Deleting user.config did not.

Answer (score 2):

search your application's product name inside `"Users \#Username#\AppData\Local"`
and delete **user.config**, then Start your app again....

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/41cfc8e2-c7f4-462d-9a43-e751500deb0a/

Comment: I don't have any config file. Eventhough it throws this error

Answer (score 0):

In my case running the program with Release config and then back on Debug solved the problem.